# Major GPA considering 2 majors

Tags: hiring-process, internship

I have two majors: one in ECE and another in Biology.

My cumulative GPA is 3.264

ECE - Major GPA with Prereqs = 3.571

ECE - Major GPA without prereqs = 3.800 (5 courses)

BIO - Major GPA with prereqs = 3.171 (Mostly Chemistry)

BIO - Major GPA without prereqs = 3.500 (2 courses)

My university doesn't list major GPA on transcript, but does list it on the web portal as the without prereqs pair.

I'm currently a Junior looking for internships in software or IC design and I'm not sure what to put on resume?

I know projects and experience is more important, but I realized that too late and while I'm working to get some, I believe Major GPA will be helpful in getting an internship.

Comment: What is ECE ? "Early Childhood Education", "Electrical & Computer Engineering", etc ??

Comment: @Hilmar, ECE = Electrical & Computer Engineering because the OP wrote "**I'm currently a Junior looking for internships in software or IC design**"

Comment: @Job_September_2020 you're right, ECE = Electrical and Computer Engineering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cumulative GPA of 3.264 is good enough to apply for an internship.

Go ahead and list this cumulative GPA on your resume.

Don't overthink about the other GPA's.